# Как в Yii2 вывести посты принадлежащие пользователю

Tags: yii2

Пытаюсь вывести посты принадлежащие конкретному пользователю. В БД имеются 2 таблицы user и  requests с полем user_id.

Делаю связь с User в модели Requests

```
 public function getUser (): ActiveQuery
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::class(),['id'=>'user_id']);
}
```

В контроллере

```
public function actionIndex()

{
    $searchModel = new RequestsSearch();
    $user_id = Yii::$app->user->id; // ID пользователя
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams)->andFilterWhere(['user_id' => $user_id]);


    return $this->render('index',
        [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,

    ]);
}
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
Calling unknown method: yii\data\ActiveDataProvider::andFilterWhere()
```

Подскажите, где ошибка?

Comment: Ошибка в RequestsSearch::search и в том, что там написано и возвращается видимо....возвращается там наверняка `dataProvider`, а метод должен вызываться на `query`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В методе search класса RequestsSearch, должен быть блок с andFilterWhere, вот там и указывать условие

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.